# How to print exponential units on BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, exponent

I think the title explains all. I have a string that I am trying to insert it on a [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) document. I found the [Exponent notation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) but I do not know if and how I can apply it on my case.

Working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_sample = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head lang="en"><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>
<body>
<div class="date">LAST UPDATE</div>
</body>
</html>
"""

si_unit = '3 m3/s'    

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_sample)
forecast = soup.find("div", {"class": "date"})
forecast.string = si_unit
print(soup.prettify())
```

Sample of Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  </meta>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="date">
   3 m3/s
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that si units is not exponential. How can I convert/print the value m(3)/s as exponent?

Does anybody know to make this tricky operation?
Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

**Update:** modifying output from 2 m3/s to 3 m3/s as on the example code given.

**Update 2:** adding working solution to my problem thanks to [jumbopap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2178164/jumbopap).

**Update 3:** modifying solution.

**Update 4:** the Unicode string that I used ref [Unicode Character 'SUPERSCRIPT THREE' (U+00B3)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00B3/index.htm), just in case someone else needs it.

First step split the string into two parts based on white space in the middle of the string. Second step, split all character into a list from the si unit part (the part that we want to modify the exponential).
Third concatenate all the characters into a new string to be pushed in BeautifulSoup.

Working code example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_sample = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head lang="en"><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>
<body>
<div class="date">LAST UPDATE</div>
</body>
</html>
"""

si_unit = '3 m3/s'
unit, si_unit = si_unit.split()
si_unit_list = list(si_unit)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_sample, 'html.parser')
forecast = soup.find("div", {"class": "date"})
forecast.string = unit + si_unit_list[0] + u"\u00B3" + si_unit_list[2] + si_unit_list[3]
print(soup.prettify())
```

And the produced output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  </meta>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="date">
   3m³/s
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note: `2 m3/s` or `3 m3/s`?

Comment: Are you looking for the <sup> tag, or the symbol ³?

Comment: @Kevin Guan, I am looking for the 3 meters to the power of three (cubic) per second. the first number it does not really matter it is just a number but the unit after it important. In conclusion 3 m(to the power of 3)/s.

Comment: @Jasper I am looking a way to make the character '3' exponential as the unit that you show. e.g. 3 m(exponential '3')/s. Is there a way to write that on BeautifulSoup?

Comment: You can use either ³ or <sup>3</sup>.

Comment: @Jasper the problem is that I need to insert a string, it can not be a fix value as this number will vary upon the measurement. So I am wondering how I can convert the character to exponential character. I am splitting the string into characters but then I do not know how to store the character as exponent and as a second step push it to BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [superscript 3 character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00B3/index.htm) in your string. You can prettify with Beautiful soup as HTML and output it.

```
>>> html = '<p>2³</p>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> out = soup.prettify(formatter="html")
>>> file('tmp.html', 'wb').write(out)
>>>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. Thanks a lot, I will update my question with a full answer to my problem for future reference.